# Understanding Modigliani & Miller: different graphs in different textbooks

Tags: finance, corporate-finance, capital-structure

I am comparing two textbook's presentations of capital structure and Modigliani & Miller propositions. The first one is Berk & DeMarzo ["Corporate Finance"](https://www.pearson.com/se/Nordics-Higher-Education/subject-catalogue/finance/corporate-finance-5e-berk-and-demarzo.html) (5th global ed., 2019), the second one is Hillier et al. "Fundamentals of Corporate Finance" (3rd ed., 2017) ([here](https://www.mheducation.co.uk/fundamentals-of-corporate-finance-4e-9781526848628-emea-group) is a link to a slightly different edition).

They seem to be illustrating the same thing but quite differently. So I guess it is **not** the same thing after all. **What is the difference** between the two books' **setups/assumptions** that makes the graphs look so different?

(Also, does it make sense that in the bottom graph (Hillier et al.), $R_D$ stays constant irrespective of the level of $D/E$? Should the lenders not require higher compensation if $D/E$ is higher?)

#### Berk & DeMarzo:

[image]

#### Hillier et al.:

[image]

Comment: The indicator measured on the horizontal axis is different, $D/(D+E)$ vs. $D/E$ ?

Comment: @Giskard, good point! But does it make sense that in the bottom graph (Hillier et al.), $R_D$ stays constant irrespective of the level of $D/E$?

Comment: Related question: [Modigliani & Miller with tax: how is this equation derived?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52465)

Answer (score 2):

The indicators measured on the horizontal axes are different, $D/(D+E)$ vs
$D/E$. Taking this into consideration we get consistent functional forms for $R_E$, but not for $R_D$.

Let $D/(D+E) = x$. Then $D/E =x/(1-x)$.

Assume that there is a functional relationship $R_E = f_1(x_1)$ in the first graph, the lower index denoting the graph. There is also a seemingly linear relationship
$R_E = R_A + bx_2$ in the second graph. Since $x_2 = x_1/(1-x_1)$, we have
$$
f_1(x_1) = R_E = R_A + b\frac{x_1}{1-x_1}.
$$
This is more or less consistent with the $f_1$ depicted in the first graph.

Since $R_A = (1-x) \cdot R_E + x \cdot R_D$, we have
$$
R_D = \frac{1}{x}R_A - \frac{1-x}{x} R_E. 
$$
In terms of the first graph this means
$$
R_D = \frac{1}{x_1}R_A - \frac{1-x_1}{x_1} f_1(x_1) = \frac{1}{x_1}R_A - \frac{1-x_1}{x_1}R_A - b = R_A - b.   
$$
This would be consistent with the depiction of $R_D$ in the second graph, but not in the first graph. (Perhaps $R_E$ is not as linear in the second graph as it seems.)

Comment: It seems likely that the model tries to make the assumption $R_D = R_A - b$, but since this is not possible at $D/V = 100\%$, some "adjustments" are necessary at this end. The problem only arises asymptotically when $D/E$ is measured, since $D/E \to 100\%$ is equivalent $D/E \to \infty$.

Comment: The second $D/E$ in the above comment should be $D/V$ (: Thus $D/V \to 100\%$ is equivalent to $D/E \to \infty$.

Comment: I get your point about the asymptotics, but does it make sense that in the bottom graph (Hillier et al.), $R_D$ stays constant irrespective of the level of $D/E$? Should the lenders not require higher compensation if $D/E$ is higher? I have also posted [another, related question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52465/modigliani-miller-with-tax-how-is-this-equation-derived) on which I am still very much lost... Could you perhaps take a look at it?